# how set ajax call by rest api parse.com

Tags: api, rest, unix, parse-platform

I'm new in rest api and i'm trying to use the api rest to associate file to object:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: qS0KL*9lFLE**S3VMk" \
  -H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: nh3***MhcKJIfIt1Gm" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{
        "name": "Andrew",
        "picture": {
          "name": "...profile.png",
          "__type": "File"
        }
      }' \
  https://api.parse.com/1/classes/PlayerProfile
```

Can anyone explain me how to set the ajax call?And what is "name":"andrew"?Is this a column named andrew in my player profile?

This is my implementation of api,but the server responded me bad request `400`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    headers: {'X-Parse-Application-Id':'qS0KLMx5h9lFLG**yhM9EEPiTS3VMk','X-Parse-REST-API-
                Key':'nh3G8D**hcKJIfIt1Gm','Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    url: "https://api.parse.com/1/users",
    data: {
        "username": "francesco",
        "picture": {
            "name": "b3b47ce2-62dc-4861-a0ad-79cfffe9b07a-foto ste.jpg",
            "__type": "File"
        }
    },

    contentType: "application/json",

    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data );
    },

    error: function(data) {
        console.log("ko" );
    }
});
```

May the api -d is wrong in my implementation.What's means `-d` in `curl`?

Comment: That's setting a column named "name" to the value "Andrew" in your PlayerProfile class.

Comment: i've added my ajax implementation but returns error 400 bad request,maybe is wrong data?

Answer (score 0):

The example in the guide shows how you can create a new PlayerProfile object and associate it with a File in a single request. Since you want to update an existing User (and not create a new one), you'll need to use the Update REST API request format. Use PUT instead of POST, then  specify which user you're referring to by appending the object id to the endpoint URL: https://api.parse.com/1/users/{objectId}.